# Include taxonomy slug in url?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

I have the following custom post-type and custom taxonomy setup:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'system',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Systems' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'System' )
            ),
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'supports' => array('title','editor','comments'),   
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'system' ),
        )
    );
}

function news_init() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'system',
        'system',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Product Category' ),
            'sort' => true,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'args' => array( 'orderby' => 'term_order' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'product-category' )
        )
    );  
}
add_action( 'init', 'news_init' );
```

Is it possible to include the custom taxonomy name in the URL?

At present when I goto a custom post the URL looks like this:

> http://www.domain/product-category/(post-name)/

How can I make it look like the following?

> http://www.domain/(category-slug)/(post-name)/

Comment: may be these plugins can be helpful https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/enhanced-custom-permalinks/

Answer (score 1):

This can be a bit challenging for WordPress, because it wouldn't know whether you are referring to post, page or taxonomy. Nevertheless, rename your taxonomy to something like `product_category` and try changing the slug in your post type arguments to `system/%product_category%`, and slug in your taxonomy arguments to just `system`. WordPress should now handle `/system/your-product-category/post-name/`

Out of the box WordPress doesn't recognize the permalink structure tag %product_category%, so we need to declare it:

```
function filter_post_type_permalink($link, $post)
{
    if ($post->post_type != 'system')
        return $link;

    if ($cats = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'product_category'))
        $link = str_replace('%product_category%', array_pop($cats)->slug, $link);
    return $link;
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'filter_post_type_permalink', 10, 2);
```

**NOTES:**

1. This will just grab the first product category for the post ordered
   by name.
2. There still may be some 404 errors, if pages, posts etc., have same names.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. No luck though. I'm still getting the 404 pages for all of the taxonomy pages. I even did the re-save permalinks to flush each time just in case but no luck.

Comment: Make sure use flush_rewrite_rules() to flush out everything. Add it to your hooks when you activate/deactivate your plugin ------------------------------------------   'register_activation_hook(   __FILE__, array( 'Your_Hook', 'on_activation' ) );
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, array( 'Your_Hook', 'on_deactivation' ) );
register_uninstall_hook(    __FILE__, array( 'Your_Hook', 'on_uninstall' ) );'

Comment: I think this worked for me, but it doesn't actually adjust the permalink, it seems. If I go to the URL I want it to be (/product-category-slug/product-slug/) I get redirected to the correct product, but it's using it's normal permalink (/products/product-slug/). This may be good enough for my purposes, but I'd like to actually have it update the permalinks.

Answer (score 1):

First off **DO NOT USE SAME POST TYPE & TAXONOMY**, In fact, you do not even need to register a taxonomy since you require category. Use the following code:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'system',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Systems' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'System' )
            ),
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'supports' => array('title','editor','comments'),   
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => '%category%' ),
        'taxonomies' => array('category')
        )
    );
}
```

Now you will have categories available for use with your 'system' post type. Also observe that I have changed the value of slug.
Now next hook up with filter *post_type_link* , this is used to replace '%category%' with the slug of category.
Use the following code:

```
function replace_system_type_category( $post_link, $id = 0 ){
    $post = get_post($id);  
    if ( is_object( $post ) ){
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'category' );
        if( $terms ){
            return str_replace( '%category%' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
        }
    }
    return $post_link;  
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'replace_system_type_category', 1, 3 );
```

The above code with replace %category% with the slug of category as required by you.
You can use the code with custom taxonomy however do not use 'system' for both post type and taxonomy.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i tested locally and it displays the taxonomy type name you create in the settings page the code adds in the permalink on taxonomy archive pages.

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpsites_create_custom_taxonomy_types' );
function wpsites_create_custom_taxonomy_types() {

register_taxonomy( 'system-type', 'system',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name'          => _x( 'Types', 'taxonomy general name', 'wpsites' ),
            'add_new_item'  => __( 'Add New System Type', 'wpsites' ),
            'new_item_name' => __( 'New System Type', 'wpsites' ),
        ),
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'hierarchical'        => true,
        'rewrite'             => array( 'slug' => 'system-type', 'with_front' => false ),
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_tagcloud'       => false,
    ));

}



add_action( 'init', 'wpsites_system_custom_post_type' );
function wpsites_system_custom_post_type() {

register_post_type( 'system',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name'          => __( 'System', 'wpsites' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'System', 'wpsites' ),
        ),
        'has_archive'  => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'menu_icon'    => 'dashicons-admin-network',
        'public'       => true,
        'rewrite'      => array( 'slug' => 'system', 'with_front' => false ),
        'supports'     => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'revisions', 'page-attributes' ),
        'taxonomies'   => array( 'system-type' ),

    ));

}
```